# How do I expose running applications on local k8s cluster to my local machine?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm deploying this project ([GitHub](https://github.com/asynkron/protoactor-grains-tutorial)) locally on k3d Kubernetes Cluster. It includes a Helm chart. There is also a documentation for this example which can be found [here](https://proto.actor/docs/cluster/getting-started-kubernetes/).

What I have done so far is what's below. It works just fine. The problem is the ClusterIPs it gives are internal for k8s and I can't access them outside of the cluster. What I want is to be able to run them on my machine's browser. I was told that I need a nodeport or a loadbalancer to do that. How can I do that?

```
// Build Docker Images
// Navigate to root directory -> ./ProtoClusterTutorial
docker build . -t proto-cluster-tutorial:1.0.0

// Navigate to root directory
docker build -f ./SmartBulbSimulatorApp/Dockerfile . -t smart-bulb-simulator:1.0.0

// Push Docker Image to Docker Hub
docker tag proto-cluster-tutorial:1.0.0 hulkstance/proto-cluster-tutorial:1.0.0
docker push hulkstance/proto-cluster-tutorial:1.0.0

docker tag smart-bulb-simulator:1.0.0 hulkstance/smart-bulb-simulator:1.0.0
docker push hulkstance/smart-bulb-simulator:1.0.0

// List Docker Images
docker images

// Deployment to Kubernetes cluster
helm install proto-cluster-tutorial chart-tutorial
helm install simulator chart-tutorial --values .\simulator-values.yaml

// It might fail with the following message:
// Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://host.docker.internal:64285/version": dial tcp 172.16.1.131:64285: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
// which means we don't have a running Kubernetes cluster. We need to create one:
k3d cluster create two-node-cluster --agents 2

// If we want to switch between clusters:
kubectl config use-context k3d-two-node-cluster

// Confirm everything is okay
kubectl get pods
kubectl logs proto-cluster-tutorial-78b5db564c-jrz26
```

Comment: please share `kubectl get svc` and `kubectl get pod` output in the namespace where your workloads run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kubectl port-forward` command.
Syntax:

```
kubectl port-forward TYPE/NAME [options] LOCAL_PORT:REMOTE_PORT
```

In your case:

```
kubectl port-forward pod/proto-cluster-tutorial-78b5db564c-jrz26 8181:PORT_OF_POD
```

Now, you can access `localhost:8181` to use.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I'm currently running it on k3d + helm chart. Quick question, this works for dev just to see that it works but about if it's in prod, will I need ingress or nodeport when I run it in prod?

Comment: Yeah, use `kubectl port-forward` when you only want to call from local, `ingress` and `nodeport` will expose on a larger scale.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you follow the official [docs](https://k3d.io/v5.4.6/usage/exposing_services/) of `k3d` for exposing services.

Use either `ingress` or `nodeport` methods.

Comment: Thanks, quick question tho. Will I need `ingress` or `nodeport` for AWS EKS in prod? Like do I need to expose the port? Right now `kubectl port-forward` works fine to me for test purposes, but what about prod in AWS EKS?

Comment: in prod you'll probably use ingress or `LoadBalancer` service type instead of `ClusterIP`

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on your use case. If you are testing from you local machine you might need to use portfowrd command `kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <localport>:<remoteport>`

If you are using Minikube then use `minikube service <service-name> --url`

If you are using a Cloud provider like AKS,GKE OR EKS then you might need to think of using some other way of accessing application this could be done by using NodePort,LoadBalancer or Ingress.

If you use service type of `Nodeport` the same could be achieved. But in the case of Nodeport service all the port ranges which it supports is **30000-32767** and this is a very hard number to memorise the port number.Another disadvantage of Nodeport service is that Node's IP address(as it changes if node restart) hence this is not used for project purposes.

Create a NodePort service : [Node port service](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/kubernetes-port-targetport-nodeport/)

`LoadBalancer` service exposes an external IP and then you can access the service using : but if you have 100 services you will be charged for 100 external IPs and this hampers the budget.

Create a load balancer service on Kubernetes : [Load Balancer service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)

Another way of exposing an application is using `ingress-controller` to achieve the same thing.Using ingress you can expose 100 applications with one external IP.You will need to install the ingress controller and then using an ingress file to configure the rules.

Setup ingress controller on Kubernetes : [Ingress controller](https://devopscube.com/setup-ingress-kubernetes-nginx-controller/)